# How to link tables correctly in SQL to add roles to staff?

Tags: sql

Currently I have a staff table with columns:

```
Staff_Id, first_name, Surname.
```

My second table is:

```
Id, management_role.
```

When I link the tables each staff member gets added to every management role. So for example a person in first table called Jim is added three times as manager, supervisor, intern and this happens for every staff.

Answer (score 0):

Some things to consider that are your ID columns are primary keys for their respective tables. If not are every value in the column is unique? Also are ids not

From your description you might be using a cross join here. The thing you need is inner join so it joins the matching id's together.

So you can do

```
SELECT *
FROM staff_table as st
INNER JOIN management_table as mt
ON st.Staff_Id = mt.ID
```